# mongodb and node.js drivers not connecting for chat rest api

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, node.js-stream

I get errors when trying to connect to mongodb while using node.js/mongodb core modules.

currently using node.js v0.10.25 and mongodb v2.6.1

One of my errors is connecting to mongodb

```
mongo.Db.connect(host, function(error, client) {                                                                                               
         ^                                                                                                                                     
TypeError: Object function (databaseName, topology, options) {
```

I also get this when running nodemon

```
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

here is my code for chat rest api

```
// first we include our libraries
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var mongo = require('mongodb');

// make a string to connect to MongoDB:
var host = "mongodb://localhost/test";

// We put all the logic inside of an open connection in the form of a callback function:
mongo.Db.connect(host, function(error, client) {
    console.log("this is working");
    if (error) throw error;

    var collection = new mongo.Collection(client, 'messages');

    var app = http.createServer( function (request, response) {

        if (request.method === "GET" && request.url === "/messages/list.json") {
            collection.find().toArray(function(error,results) {
                response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
                console.dir(results);
                response.end(JSON.stringify(results));
            });
        };

        if (request.method === "POST" && request.url === "/messages/create.json") {
            request.on('data', function(data) {
                collection.insert(querystring.parse(data.toString('utf-8')), {safe:true}, function(error, obj) {
                    if (error) throw error;
                    response.end(JSON.stringify(obj));
            })              
        })
    };
});

    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.listen(port);
})
```

Hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was establishing a connection to mongodb driver. The current method used was for mongodb v1.49 and has since been changed with the current version of mongodb v2.6.1.

Here is the updated code to reflect the needed changes to connect to the current version of mongodb.

```
    /*
     * github https://github.com/azat-co/rpjs/tree/master/mongo
     *  
     * To test via CURL terminal commands and see list of messages run: 
     * $ curl http://localhost:3000/messages/list.json 
     * 
     * NOTE: Will return empty array
     * 
     * POST a new message:
     * $ curl -d "username=BOB&message=test" http://localhost:3000/messages/create.json 
     * 
     * To add new messages:
     * $ curl -X POST -d 'name=sosana&message=waz up' http://localhost:3000/messages/create.json 
     * 
     * To check if messages worked
     * $ curl localhost:3000/messages/list.json
     * 
    */

    // first we include our libraries
    var http = require('http');
    var util = require('util');
    var querystring = require('querystring');
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var mongo = new MongoClient();

    // make a string to connect to MongoDB:
    var host = "mongodb://localhost/test";

    // We put all the logic inside of an open connection in the form of a callback function:
    mongo.connect(host, function(error, db) {
        console.log("this is working");
        if (error) throw error;

        // establish a connection to the database
        var myDB = db.db("test");

        // establish a connection to the collection 
        var collection =  myDB.collection("messages");

        var app = http.createServer( function (request, response) {

            if (request.method === "GET" && request.url === "/messages/list.json") {
                collection.find().toArray(function(error,results) {
                    response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
                    console.dir(results);
                    response.end(JSON.stringify(results));
                });
            };

            if (request.method === "POST" && request.url === "/messages/create.json") {
                request.on('data', function(data) {
                    collection.insert(querystring.parse(data.toString('utf-8')), {safe:true}, function(error, obj) {
                        if (error) throw error;
                        response.end(JSON.stringify(obj));
                })              
            })
        };
});

    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.listen(port);
    console.log("listening on port " + port);
})
```